# How to count the frequency of numbers given in a text file

Tags: python

How to count the frequency of numbers given in a text file. The text file is as follows.

```
     0
     2
     0
     1
     0
     1
     55
     100
     100
```

I want the output as follows

```
     0   3
     1   2
     2   1
     55  1
     100 2
```

I tried this without success

```
     def histogram( A, flAsList=False ):
         """Return histogram of values in array A."""
         H = {}
         for val in A:
             H[val] = H.get(val,0) + 1
         if flAsList:
             return H.items()
         return H
```

Any better way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting (and writing) word frequencies for each line within text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595574/counting-and-writing-word-frequencies-for-each-line-within-text-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). It's the best way for this type of problems

```
from collections import Counter
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fd:
    lines = fd.read().split()
    counter = Counter(lines)
    # sorts items
    items = sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
    # prints desired output
    for k, repetitions in items:
        print k,'\t', repetitions
```

The output:

```
0   3
1   2
2   1
55  1
100 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object for this:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(A)
```

Now the `c` variable will hold a frequency map of each of the values. For instance:

```
Counter(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a'])
=> Counter({'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'b': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using *update*:

```
def histogram( A, flAsList=False ):
 """Return histogram of values in array A."""
 H = {}
 for val in A:
     # H[val] = H.get(val,0) + 1
     if H.has_key(val):
        H[val] = H[val] + 1
     else:
        H.update({val : 1})
 if flAsList:
     return H.items()
 return H
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach using a dictionary:

```
histogram = {}

with open("file","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            histogram[line.strip()] +=1
        except KeyError:
            histogram[line.strip()] = 1

for key in sorted(histogram.keys(),key=int):
    print key,"\t",histogram[key]
```

Output:

```
0       3
1       2
2       1
55      1
100     2
```

**Edit:**

To select a specific column you'd want to split the line using `split()`. For example the sixth field by splitting on a single space:

```
try:
    histogram[line.strip().split(' ')[5]] +=1
except KeyError:
    histogram[line.strip().split(' ')[5]] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks sudo_O, good one because results are in increasing order. What if I need this result for a specific column in a file? Suppose numbers given in column six?